# Logic to update already scraped price in database

Tags: python, scrapy, scrape

I am using scrapy framework to scrape Name, Price and Specification of mobiles from various websites. I have scraped all the data successfully and stored it in MySQL database.

Table structure
ID || Product_Url || Name || Price || Spec ||

Now on next day some of products price's will decrease from the previous day value which is stored in my database. I want to update the price in my database

On everyday midnight one python program will run and check which of the items price is changed and if it's changed it will update the value.

I don't want to scrape all the products link again on everyday.because they are very huge in nos. Approax 20,000 links

So please guys help me with some logic that i should apply so that i only require to scrape those product links whose prices are changed.

Comment: Does the product links that you're scraping have a list of updated products, so that you can just grab that list and scrape those particular products?

Comment: No it Does not have the list of updated products

Comment: I ve also answered incase, if it does not have a list of updated products.

Answer (score 0):

1. If the product site that your scraping has a page where it lists the product links which have recently been updated, you can scrape that list, and update those products from the list.
2. But if the site does not have a page where it lists out the products which have been recently updated. You might need to scrape all the product links looking for update in prices (well its not the best solution, but it works). You can speed up the process by sending multiple requests.

   This can be configured in the project `settings`, update the `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` to the required connections that you would want to `scrapy` to send.

   Since you mentioned that there are approx. 20,000 product links, you can distribute this task of scraping this huge nos. among celery workers which will run scrapy spiders. You can run about 4 workers which will be running `scrapy` `spider` each, and be scraping 5000 links.

Ref. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

Comment: If i will Scrape all the links then how do i update the same table Because there will be three cases, Now i will have some new products listed on that page and some of products prices are changed are some prices are not changed

Comment: you can distribute the scraping task among multiple celery workers which will query your single database, and will compare the scraped value with the existing value, and update the DB values. And it will also check if the scraped product exists in the DB, and if not it will insert a new record for the new product.

Comment: But you need to distribute the task such that a single worker only processes a range of products (you can use the product ID as reference). For eg. for product IDs (in range 1 to 500) worker A will update records for these products. And for product IDs (in range 500 to 1000) worker B will be updating their values. And everytime you come across a  record which does not exist in the DB, you need insert a record for each. So everytime before inserting a record, you can query for existing records.

Comment: ok so as i am using mysql i will use  Insert into Tablename (product_url, Name, price) values(xxx,xxx,555)  on Duplicate Key Update price = if( values(price)!= price, values(price), price ) and updated_status=1

Comment: which mysql python driver are using?

Comment: I am using MySqlDb python wrapper

Comment: Ok! The update query syntax seems to be right! But before inserting just check for existing records, by using a select query.

Comment: ya i am checking wheter the record exist or not in above statement itself

Comment: Then this solution should work for you! For speeding up the scraping process, you can just increase the number of celery workers (spiders) evenly.

Comment: where product_url is the unique key so if that product is alraedy in databse it will not insert it as new entry but only update the price of that entry

Comment: Yep! And instead of using the product url, just try to split the product_url (and get the product path) from the url! That will less overhead

Comment: but here is one more confusion i want to update the status=1 only if price is updated how to do that??

Comment: instead of using update_status, try using a datetime object! something like last_updated time! That should be more convinient

Comment: Create a new field in your DB, with is of a datetime (refer to Mysql syntax) and use python's `datetime` module for updating the date. When updating the last_updated timestamp, just assign `datetime.datetime.now()` this will return the current timestamp.